# Getting callback to behave synchronously

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with Javascript Callbacks. I have a class hierachy that all have a method getVisual() which return a visual representation of the given object. All of them work nicely and synchronously. For one more class in the hierachy that I am just implementing now to introduce a new feature during getVisual() I need to wait for an Image.onload() to finish get the visual representation. As the getVisual() methods of all the classes is synchronous I have a problem I guess. And the only way I see is to either figure out a way to wait for onload to finish - which according to all stackoverflow articles I read is not recommended - or I would have to completely change my application architecture for the caller of getVisual() to only request a visual and offer a method to be called once the visual has been created. I really would hate to change the whole architecture because of one single operation. Is there any way around it?
Cheers T

Comment: Can you post some code snippets of what you've already attempted?

Comment: *"Is there any way around it?"* Most likely not.

Comment: Promises and callbacks or Async/Await are the way to make asynchronous code synchronous. Until you post some of your code, though, we don't know how to help you.

Comment: @mhodges They don't make anything synchronous, the code still runs asynchronously (and it's impossible to change that). All they do is provide nicer syntax for running tasks sequentially.

Comment: @Bergi Meh, semantics. If you put code in a Promise callback, that code is now running synchronously just as it would if the code was after a synchronous call. I guess better language would be "make asynchronous code *behave* synchronously"